# error: expected expression before 'student'

Tags: c, struct

very new to c. I wrote the following code.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[100];
    int comp, math, phys;
    int total;
} student[100];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int number;

do
{
    printf("Enter how many students: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number < 0)
    {
       printf("Wrong input! \n"); 
    }
}
while(number < 0);

int i;

for(i=0; i < number; ++i)
{
    printf("Student %d's name: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", student[i].name);
    printf("Comp: " );
    scanf("%d", &student[i].comp);
    printf("Phys: " );
    scanf("%d", &student[i].phys);
    printf("Math: " );
    scanf("%d", &student[i].math);
    &student[i].total = &student[i].comp + &student[i].math + &student[i].phys;
}

printf("s%", &student[1].name);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I keep getting error: expected expression before 'student' in all the scanf lines and the last printf line. What am I doing wrong? Very new to C so any help would be great.

Comment: You are attempting to use `student` as an array *object*. But you declared it as an array *type*. Types and objects are two completely different things.

Comment: In the line starting `&student[i].total =`, take out all the `&`

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
struct
{
    char name[100];
    int comp, math, phys;
    int total;
} student[100];
```

If you want to combine the definition and identifier. You should know that student isn't a type, it's an array of structs without a name. There are alternatives to what you want to accomplish. For example:

```
typedef struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int comp, math, phys;
    int total;
} student;

student students[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `typedef` keyword. You're wanting to create an array of 100 student objects, not a type name representing an array of 100 students.

Hopefully this helps you in the future:

```
// `Type var` is a shorter way to write `struct tag var`
// `Type` is just an alias (another name) for `struct tag`
typedef struct tag {
    int x;
} Type;

// `Type100 arr` is a shorter way to write `struct tag100 arr[100]`
// `Type100` is just an alias for `struct tag100[100]`
// No, you can't do `struct tag100[100] arr`; `Type100 arr` gets around this restriction
typedef struct tag100 {
    int x;
} Type100[100];

// `var` contains a single value of type `struct tagX`
struct tagX {
    int x;
} var;

// `arr` is an array of 100 values of type `struct tagX100`
struct tagX100 {
    int x;
} arr[100];
```